# matching a word only if it is unique

Tags: javascript, regex

I've spent the day trying to use regex to match a word only where the word is unique.  It's not working and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I need something that will match only a unique instance of "ST", such as:

- "1 MARY **ST** WASHINGTON"

but fail with these:

- "1 **ST** MARY **ST** WASHINGTON"
- "1 **ST** MARY **ST** MT **ST** HELENS"
- "1 MARY RD WE**ST** WASHINGTON"
- "1 MARY RD WASHINGTON"

I thought this lookahead would work, but no such luck:

```
(\bST\b)(?!(\bST\b))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following pattern:

```
^(?!(.*\bST\b){2,}).*\bST\b
```

This does a negative lookahead right away in which it checks if there are 2 or more occurrences of `\bST\b`. If there aren't, it moves on in the pattern and checks if there is at least one.

Comment: Hi spaark, I’ve been trying your formula on regex101.com, but it isn’t matching anything. Your approach makes logical sense, and the formula looks right (to my untrained eye), but might there be a typo I’m not seeing?

Comment: @sjh It seems to work for me https://regex101.com/r/cxVuvk/2, at least insofar as it matches the correct line.

Comment: Yes, you may need to activate multiline if you test with all the lines in sequence.

Comment: Got it. I do believe I have an answer. Thanks spaark. I’ve also started a deep dive into regex - I’m certainly going to have to rewind a bunch of neurones to get a hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` `/\bST\b/g` and `.match()`, check `.length` of matched string

```js
const matches = (str, re = /\bST\b/g, match = str.match(re)) => 
                  !!match && match.length === 1;

const arr = [
"1 MARY ST WASHINGTON"
, "1 ST MARY ST WASHINGTON"
, "1 ST MARY ST MT ST HELENS"
, "1 MARY RD WEST WASHINGTON"
, "1 MARY RD WASHINGTON"
];

console.log(arr.map(s => matches(s)));
```

Comment: Hi guest271314, thanks, though I had hoped to use the regex as an arg in a cascading series of inline .replace(arg, “replacement”) operations.  I played around with the idea of prototyping a new String function: String.uniquereplace(), but it seemed to me that there must be a neat regex-only formula that would avoid prototyping.

Comment: @sjh _"I had hoped to use the regex as an arg in a cascading series of inline .replace(arg, “replacement”) operations"_ `.replace()` is not mentioned at original Question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoeverflow.com/help/mcve. What is expected result of `.replace()` called on the strings which should "fail"?